# Function growth: $n!$ vs $n^{\log n}$

Tags: asymptotics

I have a problem where I have to compare two functions and tell which one grows faster:

$$f(n) = n!, \quad g(n) = n^{\log_2n}.$$

However, I do not know how to tell which one is greater or reduce them with the limit definition. If I decompose both function I get
$$n! = n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots1$$
and
$$n^{\log_2n} = \underbrace{n·n·n\cdots}_{\log_2n \text{ times}}.$$

My intuition tells me $n!$ is bigger, because the $\log_2n$ grows very slowly so the accumulated product of $n$ must grow slower than $n!$.

Thank you.

Comment: Just one remark : the definition of $n^{\mathrm{log}_2 n}$ is not the one you gave, because "$\mathrm{log}_2 n$ times" has no sense (it's not an integer). The good definition is the exponential definition $a^b = e^{b \ln a}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Stirling's formula, we see that
\begin{align}
n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left( \frac{n}{e}\right)^n
\end{align}
Then it follows
\begin{align}
\frac{n!}{n^{\log_2 n}} \sim  \sqrt{2\pi n}\frac{n^{n-\log_2 n}}{e^n} = \sqrt{2\pi n} e^{(n-\log_2 n)\log_e n-n}\gg \sqrt{n}
\end{align}
for $n\gg 1$.